# вывод полей таксономии Drupal 7 во views

Tags: drupal

Возможен ли вывод полей словаря таксономии во вьювс? Например используя какой либо модуль, пробовал tvi, но насколько я понял он только заменяет стандартный вывод словаря на вьюшку.
Мне же нужно - вывести 3-4 отмеченных мной термина в таком виде:

- изображение термина
- тайтл термина
- дескрипшен термина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку версию `Drupal` вы не указали, то дальнейшее описание верно для `Drupal 7`.

1. Добавляем новое представление: *Структура* - *Представления* - *Добавить новое представление*. Настраиваем новое представление:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Добавляем нужные поля в вывод: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, добрый человек, прям огромнейшее. Все оказалось так просто)

Comment: @phpred не за что. Если ответ вас устраивает, вы можете нажать галочку слева, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: да, отлично, спасибо, не заметил